# Getting error while logging in 402 (Payment Required)

Tags: node.js, express

I don't understand it. I am not able to login. User is already in my database, and when I log in, it simply says:

**`POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login 402 (Payment Required)`**

When I register for the first time, and then login, login is successful. If I  logout, and then try to log in with that same email and password, it's throwing me the above error. I'm not even using someone's API. It's my own created one. It's sending me a response of `"incorrect password"`

Here's the controller:

```js
loginUser: (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body

    if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
    }

    User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
        } else if (!user) {
            return res.status(402).json({ error: "User not found" })
        } else if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
            return res.status(402).json({ error: "incorrect password" })
        } 
    })
}
```

**`User model`**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, reuired: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    posts:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]
}, { timestamps: true })


userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    if (this.password) {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt)
    }
    next()
})

userSchema.methods.confirmPassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)
}

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

**`registration controller`**

```js
    registerUser: (req, res) => {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        User.create(req.body, (err, createdUser) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error occurred" })
            } else if (!username || !email || !password) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username, email and password are must" })
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invaid email" })
            } else if (password.length < 6) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters" })
            }
            else {
                return res.status(200).json({ user: createdUser })
            }
        })
    }
```

**`Edit`**

```
loginUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body

    if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
    }

    await User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) { 
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
        } else if (!user) {
            return res.status(402).json({ error: "User not found" })
        } else if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
            return res.status(402).json({ error: "incorrect password" })
        } 
    })
}
```

**`new post controller`**

```
    newPost: (req, res) => {

    const data = {
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
      user: req.user.userId
    }

    Post.create(data, (err, newPost) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
      } else if (!newPost) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "No Post found" })
      } else if (newPost) {
        User.findById(req.user.userId, (err, user) => {
          user.posts.push(newPost._id) //pushing posts documnet objectid to the post array of the user document
          user
            .save()
            .then(() => {
              return res.json(200).json({ user })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
            })
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: What does your `user` object look like and what does your `confirmPassword` function look like?

Comment: `compareSync` is a promise and you are returning it as promise (correct), but in your `User.findOne` handler you treat it as a synchronous operation. It might be causing the problem.

Comment: Is the value of `this` in the `userSchema.pre("save",... ` the correct value? Same for `this` in `userSchema.methods.confirmPassword`?

Comment: Hey it's working fine, but there's one problem. I register, login and logout. First I register  login, make a post and then logout with Sam. Again I register, login, make a post, and then logout with John. 
After that, I try to log in, but it throws me that same 402 error. No matter with which user i am trying to log in.

Comment: Try logging/debugging the functionality in the user save `userSchema.pre("save",...` function AFTER creating a post. Is the data consistent? Is the value of `this` correct? Also check the `user` object in the json response in the `then` after `save`.

Comment: Yeah, the hashed password has changed. Look here https://hastebin.com/nukoyaguro.coffeescript

Comment: any solutions for this @MattCroak?

Comment: Working on one now. I think I know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to refactor your code so that you do the `bcrypt` operations in controller not in the model. You are checking `this.password` after the user is updated (creating new posts) and since `this` is the user, the below code is being met each time you update the user object.

```
if (this.password) {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt)
}
```

So your hashing it every time you update the user (create a post). Instead, remove the above code from the `userSchema.pre(...)` and try doing the `bcrypt` hashing only when the user **first** registers.

```
registerUser: (req, res) => {
        var { username, email, password } = req.body
        if (password) {
           const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
           password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
        }
        User.create(req.body, (err, createdUser) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error occurred" })
            } else if (!username || !email || !password) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username, email and password are must" })
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invaid email" })
            } else if (password.length < 6) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters" })
            }
            else {
                return res.status(200).json({ user: createdUser })
            }
        })
    }
```

This way the hashing occurs only once at the creation of the user and should remain consistent throughout other operations.

As for the `Can't set headers after they are sent` error, you might be sending a response twice, since the error appears to come from the `posts` controller. You are likely sending the user response and the post response. Maybe don't send the posts response since you will be sending it along in the user response.

More info on the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149589/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Moreover, I've seen that password hashing is generally done in the pre save hook. So, doing it in controller seems fine?

Comment: Glad it worked. It doesn’t matter where you do it really but I think if you do it in the pre save hook you need to indicate that the password has changed. If you do it every time it will eventually hash the hashed password which is probably what was happening in your case.